# how to disallow history in vb.net web browser

Tags: php, vb.net

I have a vb.net program that allows you to access webpages in my localhost. 
Now, my problem is that, when I try to list records in mysql by using tables, it remembers history and the previous data that you listed will appear like a ghost even if the data you inputted does not correspond to the data that it is showing. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
```